# Ho to show/hide buttons and table controllers based on conditions set in the groovy script in SAP Advanced Workflow

Tags: groovy, workflow, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm using the following code in my groovy script to hide or show a button and a table controller in the form. But this is not working and not making any difference in the show/hide of the screen elements. This script is called on a button click in SAP advanced workflow form.

```
form.getButton(<button_name>).hide()
form.getWidget(<table_controller_name>).hide()
```

and

```
form.getButton(<button_name>).show()
form.getWidget(<table_controller_name>).show()
```

If someone can hep me in finding where I'm missing something then it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Are there errors, logs, stacktraces? Or is it just not resulting in any visual effect?

Comment: No error, just that it is not making any difference in the show/hide of the elements involved.

Comment: Please note: don't use [tag:sap], better use [tag:sap-business-technology-platform] which is the closest tag corresponding to SAP Advanced Workflow. Please choose the tags according to their [tag usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap): "*DO NOT USE THIS TAG as it's ambiguous.*" See Stack Overflow help to learn more about Stack Overflow usage.